# Formatting IMPORTXML Xpath query into readable data for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, split, google-query-language, textjoin

I am importing XML data to a google sheet which has the following structure:
edit: URL: https://sonicstate.com/news/tools/revive_stats/client_camp_3785.xml

```
<data>
    <campaignId>15802</campaignId>
    <campaignName>Some name</campaignName>
      <startDate>
       <year>2021</year>
       <month>12</month>
       <day>02</day>
     </startDate>
     <endDate>
       <year>2021</year>
       <month>12</month>
       <day>13</day>
     </endDate>
</data>
<data>
.... another record
</data>
```

I want the results of multiple rows to be imported with date values concatenated so they can appear in manageable rows in the sheet I can then query while the other values will appear in their own cells with a row for each record.
eg

> 15802  |  Some name | 2021/12/02 | 2021/12/13

> 15803  |  Another name | 2021/11/30 | 2021/12/04

I have tried:

```
IMPORTXML("myurl" , "//data/campaignId | //data/campaignName | //data/startDate/year | //data/startDate/month|//data/startDate/day")
```

But each value returns on a separate row with cells for year, month, day
eg:

```
15802
Some Name
Year | Month | Day
15802
Another Name
Year | Month | Day
etc
```

I also tried:

```
IMPORTXML("myurl" , "concat(//data/campaignId , //data/campaignName , //data/startDate/year,'/', //data/startDate/month,'/',//data/startDate/day")
```

But that only returns a single record. I'm struggling to find the right terms to search for what I am trying to achieve. Also Sheets XMLIMPORT uses XPath 1.0 which limits the functions available

Comment: share the url...

Comment: Added to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(IF(0=MOD(ROW(A:A)-1, 5)-{0, 1, 4, 3, 2}, {"♦","","","",""}&TEXT(
 IMPORTXML(A1, "//data/campaignId|//data/campaignName|//data/startDate/year|//data/startDate/month|//data/startDate/day"), 
 {"@","@","@","@","@"})&{"♠","♠","","♣","♣"}, ))),,9^9)),,9^9), "♦")), "♠")), "♣ ", "/"))
```

[image]

### [formula explanation](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G5ClGPjAdMltTD5Ju37zj7B5BR99O7k-ycoG5xedcUM/edit#gid=385434737)

---

shorter fx:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(IFNA(
 CHOOSE(MATCH(MOD(SEQUENCE(999)-1, 5), {0, 1}), "♦", )&
 IMPORTXML(A1, "//data/campaignId|//data/campaignName|//data/startDate/year|//data/startDate/month|//data/startDate/day")&
 CHOOSE(MATCH(MOD(SEQUENCE(999)-1, 5), {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}), "♠","♠","♣","♣","")),,9^9), "♦")), "♠")), "♣ ", "/"))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thats intense! It worked (took a while to populate) I need to figure out how to expand it to pull more data in - gonna take me a little while to figure out whats going on but a brilliant and single request solution.

Comment: Ok, I need to add the  enddate (also formatted) and impressions values in there for each row but, I just cant decipher what you did, much to my shame! 
I figured that I should be able to figure that out from any answers I got  but your expertise is way beyond mine.

Comment: @Nowski see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G5ClGPjAdMltTD5Ju37zj7B5BR99O7k-ycoG5xedcUM/edit#gid=385434737

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much for your assistance, I will take a look at that and figure out what I need from it. Much appreaciated

Comment: @Nowski added shorter alternative

Comment: absolutely clever/smart !

Comment: Thanks! I did get the long version working. Now I just saw the shorter version, not figured out how to add more bits of information to shorter one though. 
Now I have to figure out how to loop that over the selected importxml sources to create a neat row of results (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795698/google-sheets-increment-formula-in-next-available-row)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

in A1 : your url

in A2 : your function without any change

in B1 : put 5 as you request 5 values per item

in B2 :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A2:A)/B1),B1,ROW(A2)),{ROW(A2:A),A2:A},2,0))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nFcPgXgRc11-WWICG8Y8KEsB4qAoOt1lIbptHzXdC4M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX({IMPORTXML(A1, "//data/campaignId"),
 IMPORTXML(A1, "//data/campaignName"), 
 IMPORTXML(A1, "//data/startDate/day")&"/"&
 IMPORTXML(A1, "//data/startDate/month")&"/"&
 IMPORTXML(A1, "//data/startDate/year")})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that would certainly work,but  due to the number of IMPORTXML alreeady in this sheet it may well overload the number of requests, I am already seeing some loading issues and was looking for a way to reduce the number of calls to that fuction