# Google Sheets Increment formula in next available row

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to populate a data set from multiple IMportXML functions.

```
In CELL A1
=IMPORTXML('Referencesheet'!C1, "//data")
```

which returns a dynamic number of rows eg 4.

In the next available row (5)
I want:

```
In Cell A5
=IMPORTXML('ReferenceSheet'!C2,"//data")
```

Which may return 8 rows (or whatever).

And so on. So I can automatically populate a data set and query it.
Is there a way to tell Sheets to use the next available row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create array of `IMPORTXML's` using brackets `{}` and separate functions by semicolon, e.g.

```
={IMPORTXML('Referencesheet'!C1, "//data");IMPORTXML('ReferenceSheet'!C2,"//data")}
```

the results will be arranged one below the other

[image]

Comment: Thats great. My only problem is that my IMPORTXML function is really complex so building an array out of it is very unwieldy. Wondering about how to simplify that